# Как собрать проект в Idea в один исполняемый JAR со всеми зависимостями, без maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

Друзья помогите чайнику. Написал простейшую консольную программку в пару классов. Из особенностей подключил logback для записи логов работы.
Хочу собрать проект в один jar, без использования maven.
Вроде настроил artifact, при его сборке создается jar, в нем в папке lib 3 библиотеки. Но в манифесте не указан class-path.
А при запуске jar выдается ошибка:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
        at Main.<clinit>(Main.java
```

Что я не так делаю, может надо руками манифест подправить?
Подскажите плиз, т.к. при запуске проекта из Idea все работает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать Maven или Gradle?

Comment: Потому что не умею. Создал проект мавен. вот такой pom.xml получился https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bycWx9sExtiK0TKF-_kYQg7yUkIZlZj4/view?usp=sharing но в таком случае зависимости попадают в папку target/lib а не в конечный jar. Почему то в манифест не прописался  class-path и в итоге при запуске jar таже ошибка. Если вы мне поможете с правильным pom.xml в котором будут эти 3 зависимости и при сборке они будут попадать в конечный jar и он будет запускаться без ошибок, это будет просто супер!!!

Comment: Использовал maven-shade-plugin для сборки и все заработало

Comment: Отлично, здесь конечно дело вкуса, но я также советую вам научится работать с Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Использовал maven-shade-plugin для сборки и все заработало